# Outputting XML to file

Tags: sql, xml, plsql

I am brand new to XML as well as SQL procedures, and I am trying to get this to output to a .txt (or .xml?) on one of our UNIX server. I have been looking at various things online, but having trouble getting it right. Could someone push me in the right direction?

```
create or replace procedure markviewimport_interface (p_invoice_id number(10), p_filename nvarchar(30))
is
    v_output clob;

begin

SELECT  
            XMLFOREST(
                XMLCONCAT(
                        XMLELEMENT("CREATEDBY",XMLATTRIBUTES('Exported By' AS "header"), 'Magellan IT'),
                        XMLELEMENT("TIMESTAMP",XMLATTRIBUTES('Date' AS "header"), TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'MM.DD.YYYY')),
                        XMLFOREST(
                            XMLFOREST(
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'invoice_id' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Invoice ID' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.invoice_id AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'vendor_num' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Vendor Num' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.vendor_num AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'vendor_name' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Vendor Name' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.vendor_name AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'po_number' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'PO Number' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.po_number AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'invoice_date' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Invoice Date' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.invoice_date AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'invoice_num' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Invoice Number' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.invoice_num AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'terms_name' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Terms Date' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.terms_name AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'invoice_amount' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Invoice Amount' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.invoice_amount AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'amount_applicable_to_discount' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Amount Applicable to Discount' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.amount_applicable_to_discount AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'amount_paid' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Amount Paid' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.amount_paid AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'payment_date' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Payment Date' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.payment_date AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'filename' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'File Name' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.filename AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'complete_filename' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Complete File Name' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.complete_filename AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'document_id' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Document ID' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.document_id AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'text' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Text' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.text AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM",
                                XMLFOREST(
                                    'tool_name' AS "DBFIELD",
                                    'Tool Name' AS "CAPTION",
                                    r_markviewimport.tool_name AS "VALUE"
                                ) AS "DATA_ITEM"
                            ) AS "BASICDATA"
                        )       
                    ) AS "DATA_ROOT"
                ) .getclobval() into v_output  
FROM             
( 
SELECT DISTINCT inv.invoice_id, 
                    vendor.segment1 vendor_num, 
                    vendor.vendor_name, 
                    poh.segment1 po_number, 
                    inv.invoice_date, 
                    inv.invoice_num, 
                    terms.name terms_name, 
                    inv.invoice_amount, 
                    inv.amount_applicable_to_discount, 
                    inv.amount_paid, 
                    pmt.check_date payment_date, 
                    path.filename, 
                    path.complete_filename, 
                    path.document_id, 
                    stamps.text, 
                    stamps.tool_name 
    FROM            apps.ap_invoices_all inv, 
                    apps.ap_invoice_distributions_all dist, 
                    apps.po_distributions_all podi, 
                    apps.ap_invoice_payment_history_v pmt, 
                    apps.fnd_attached_docs_form_vl fnd, 
                    markview.mv_page_image_paths path, 
                    apps.po_vendors vendor, 
                    apps.po_headers_all poh, 
                    apps.ap_terms terms, 
                    ( 
                           SELECT mp.document_id, 
                                  moi.markup_object_id, 
                                  moi.page_markups_view_id, 
                                  moi.text, 
                                  mvt.tool_name, 
                                  mp.page_id 
                           FROM   markview.mv_markup_object moi, 
                                  markview.mv_tool mvt, 
                                  markview.mv_page_markups_view mpmv, 
                                  markview.mv_page mp 
                           WHERE  moi.tool_id = mvt.tool_id 
                           AND    mp.page_id = mpmv.page_id 
                           AND    mpmv.page_markups_view_id = moi.page_markups_view_id 
                           AND    mvt.tool_id IN 
                                  ( 
                                         SELECT mvt.tool_id 
                                         FROM   markview.mv_tool 
                                         WHERE  mvt.tool_name IN ( 'Green Text', 
                                                                  'Blue Sticky Note' ) )) stamps
    WHERE           inv.invoice_id = to_number(fnd.pk1_value) 
    AND             inv.invoice_id = dist.invoice_id 
    AND             poh.po_header_id(+) = podi.po_header_id 
    AND             podi.po_distribution_id(+) = dist.po_distribution_id 
    AND             fnd.file_name = to_char(path.document_id) 
    AND             inv.invoice_id = pmt.invoice_id 
    AND             path.document_id = stamps.document_id(+) 
    AND             path.page_id = stamps.page_id(+) 
    AND             fnd.category_description = 'MarkView Document' 
    AND             fnd.entity_name = 'AP_INVOICES' 
    AND             inv.vendor_id = poh.vendor_id(+) 
    AND             inv.terms_id = terms.term_id 
    AND             inv.vendor_id = vendor.vendor_id 
    AND             path.platform_name = 'UNIX_FS_TO_DOC_SERVER' 
    AND             pmt.void = 'N'
    --AND inv.invoice_id = 4796324

DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file(v_output, 'My Directory', 'output.xml');
) r_markviewimport
```

Here is my procedure, where am I going wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: That's a vast chunk of code with no supporting information regarding its purpose or the underlying, or even a definition of what you mean *"having trouble getting it right"*. I think you overestimate our powers. All we  know about your code is what post here. You need to provide a lot more in the way of context if you want anyone to help.

Comment: My apologies. So this code generates the XML how I want it. Once I added the following (v_output clob;

&

DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.clob2file(v_output, 'My Directory', 'output.xml');) in order to get this to output to a .xml file it does not work. 

Basically I want this to output to an .xml file and have no idea where to start. I just know that the xml generation along with the select statement is correct.

Comment: So all the code you posted is not really relevant to the actual problem you need solving?

Comment: I mean, its basis and most meaningful part of the thing I'm trying to do and gives context to the problem I'm having. I'd call that relevant.

Comment: Your comments suggest that you have a working XML query which produces the output in the format you want. Your problem is you don't know how to write that output to a file. Is that right? If so, your question as it stands is misleading and off-putting, because the way it's framed makes people think they need to work their through that vast screeds of code. You are more likely to get the answer you need it you rewrite your question with a much simpler token XML query and an accurate problem statement. Entirely up to you of course.

Comment: Why not just use a server language (Python, PHP, Java) to connect to Oracle, run this procedure, and output results to file?

Comment: @APC Ah, I see what you mean now. Yes it produces the output I want, I just cannot get it to write to a file.

Comment: @Parfait I didn't actually know that I could do that.

Comment: Indeed, SQL is a special-purpose language designed to query databases, while general-purpose languages can do many things: connect to APIs, text/binary file i/o, file system handling, etc.

Comment: i've answered you in here [xml to file](i've answered you in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815186/how-to-write-xml-to-file-pl-sql/48821583#48821583). Which part is not clear? What is this `My Directory` ?